# Assembly x86 to machine code

Tags: x86, x86-16

I need this 3 commands on asm and machine code:

I'm not sure about syntax

```
mov ebp, 11707336    ; move 11707336hex to register ebp

sal ebp, 8           ; shift left 8 bits (I need 70733600 at ebp)

jmp 66661149         ; I guess that in machine code it will be offset and not a direct
                     ; address, so this command is at 0012ED1C
```

thanks.

Comment: I suggest you take the same reverse engineering too you used to find these(?) to patch it. You know that it is rather odd to have absolute label addresses and the only goal I can think of is software protection removal

Comment: If you want to load a hex number, you have to specify that it's hex. For example, `11707336h`.

Comment: this is a "pseudo code", I need it in binary. it's such a big deal to translate it?

Answer (score 3):

i think you have to use `jmp` with a `label` in your code.
if you want to move to `adress 66661149`  you have to load it in a register
and then load it to your `programm counter or stack pointer`.
and if you want to load hex constant's use 0x a.e. 0xFFFFF

i dindn't know what your question is but i think you want to know if your asm code is correct?

http://zsmith.co/intel/intel_j.html#jmp

the instruction set: http://zsmith.co/intel/intel.html

Comment: it's not a program. it is an input for function, so I need it in machine code, and don't need it in asm at all. and I haven't got a possibility to add labels or something like this. the only things I know - addresses.

Comment: than search the opcodes to your instructions or compile it and look at it's binary output.

Comment: good advice... I thought that it will be a slightly faster to ask smb here who remember such things, and not learn the architecture and search the opcodes.. when I wrote on pdp11, it wasn't a problem to me to translate code to binary...

Comment: but maybe you could it write as inline asm in your f.e. C code